# Param is missing or the value is empty yet param.require(:event).permit is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to create a new resource, I get "param is missing for the value is empty".  In Terminal, it reads as:

```
Started POST "/events" for ::1 at 2021-06-22 04:26:53 -0500
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Create Event"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "41f0d4cc-5ef0-4994-8a5f-3786faf33eec"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms | Allocations: 1991)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: event
Did you mean?  controller
               authenticity_token
               commit
               action):
  
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:48:in `event_params'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

my events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @event = Event.new
    
    if current_user&.admin_role?
        render layout: "admin/base"
    end
  end
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: "Video was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

the form itself is:

```
= form_with url: events_path do |f|
  
  -#= render 'events/forms/parts/errors'
  -#= render 'events/forms/parts/basic_info', f: f
  .d-grid.gap-2.d-md-block.p-4.bg-light
    = f.submit "Create Event", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"
    = link_to 'Cancel', events_path, class: "btn btn-secondary btn-lg", role: "button"
```

While I do have the renders commented out for this thread, I get the error with or without them commented out.  Trying to do a process of elimination.  Tested a different controller that has similar setup and that one works fine.

I see in the Terminal readout it's not using the parameters defined in the event_params anyway.

**Update**
Here is the other two form partials:
_errors.html.haml

```
- if @event.errors.any?
  .alert.alert-warning.border.border-dark{role: "alert"}
    %h2 #{pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error")} prevented us from processing the form:
    %ul
      - event.errors.each do |error|
        %li= error.full_message
```

and _basic_info.html.haml

```
.form-floating.mb-4
  = f.text_field :title, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Event Title"
  = f.label :title, "Event Title"
  
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.url_field :cover_img, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Cover Image URL"
      = f.label :cover_img, "Cover Image URL"
      
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.text_field :cover_img_alt, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Description of the cover image"
      = f.label :cover_img_alt, "Description of the cover image"
      
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.datetime_field :start, placeholder: "Start Date and Time", class: "form-control border border-dark"
      = f.label :start, "Start Date and Time"
      
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.datetime_field :end, placeholder: "End Date and Time", class: "form-control border border-dark"
      = f.label :end, "End Date and Time"
      
.row
  .col-md-6.mb-4
    .form-floating
      = f.text_field :category, class: "form-control border border-dark", placeholder: "Category"
      = f.label :category, "Category"
    
.form-group
  = f.label :registration_url, "Registration URL"
  = f.url_field :registration_url, class: "form-control"
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :registration_full, "Registration is Full"
  = f.check_box :registration_full, class: "form-check"
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :registration_required, "Registration required"
  = f.check_box :registration_required, class: "form-check"
  
.form-group.mb-4
  = f.label :description, "Description"
  = f.text_area :description, class: "form-control"
```

I'm only testing it with :title and :description at the moment because that's all the model requires:

events model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, presence: :true
    validates :description, presence: :true
    ...
end
```

I don't even have a form field called authenticity_token but suspect it might be auto generated by Rails.

Comment: because you are requiring an event, your params need an event symbol in them.   Your parameters are this `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Create Event"}` and that needs an event in it `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Create Event", "event"=>{"title"=> 'some title', "description"=> 'some descrip."}}` or something.  So this issue is with your form set up but I'm not sure exactly where without the other partial's code included in here.

Answer (score 1):

Its because, in your event_params method you are telling to require the event params and then its attributes as a params, but in your form you are not passing the Event model instance for the form to create events params.
Try using form_for form generator and passing the @event instance to it.

```
= form_for @event do |f|
```

Comment: form_for @event also return the same results.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did to solve the issue.

I cloned the working version of my app that I had in staging where everything was working fine versus my refactoring.

I see the controller is the same basically for the affected parts.  so ruminating a bit this morning I decided to test each file one by one.

new.html.haml comparison: only real difference is that the clone passed

```
event: @event
```

into the events/forms/new/form partial.

Moving on to the form partial itself, as it still didn't work with or without passing the instance variable, I copied and pasted the cloned code into the refactored code and testing it in a web browser.  Worked like a charm.  So what was the issue?  hit undo to go back to the refactored code.  Doesn't work.  Tested the Create button by itself inside and outside of the CSS div.  still no.

Then I played with the partials I had commented out.

1. the errors partial didn't pass the instance variable into it, so that partial wouldn't work properly without that information.
2. The culprit here was the basic_info partial, which includes the :title and :description params.  Commenting out this partial I get "param is missing" error, but turning it back on it works fine.